# Datatables: using mRender to display image not working

Tags: image, datatables

Referring to this page: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#mRender

I'm attempting to display an image from a database reference.

I need to display images on the very first column.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _dataTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
            "aoColumns": [
              {
                  "mData": "logo",
                  "mRender": "[, ].name"
                    }

            ]
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _dataTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                "aTargets": [0],
                "mData": "logo",
                "aoColumns": [{
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<img src="' + data + '"></>'
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
```

This is a bit over my head at this time, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's close, you just need to use `full[]` to access the data:

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full) {
       return '<img src="' + full[0] + '"></>';
   }
```

Some points to note:

I've assumed that you're returning a string representing the image name & filepath, and you have a folder of images on the server somewhere.  If you're storing images in the database as binary data this won't work.

I've used `full[0]` assuming the image path is the first column of data - obviously if it's not the first column then you need to change the index value.

The returned image string will have to be the full path to the physical image location otherwise you'll have to prepend it with the path to get it to show.

Also, you were missing a semicolon at the end of the return statement.